# Is Auto-response also sent to a person who mail to a group in which I am a member?

Tags: email, gmail, auto-responder

Recently I have activated auto-responder in my gmail account. I am aware that if someone mail me, she will get the massage. But If I am mailed indirectly, that is, if I am a member of a group and someone mail in that group, then will she find the auto-response too? Or, the person who mail me directly by writing my gmail account in address bar will only get the auto-response?